Styling the new Google Maps Autocomplete input
The new Google Maps Autocomplete input elements works great, but as far as I can tell it has one major drawback - you can't style it.
Because it loads after the DOM is complete and is encapsulated within a Shadow DOM, I can't add CSS anywhere or use a listener to change it after it's loaded. And there are no styling options in the API that I can find in the docs.
Has anyone overcome this issue and managed to style the autocomplete input?
